# Why $P(A) \cup P(B)$ is not equivalent to $P(A \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that they are equivalent if we have $\cap$ instead of $\cup$.

If we start from left, we have:

$X \in P(A) \cup P(B)$

$X \subset A \lor X \subset B$

If we start from right, we have:

$X \in P(A \cup B)$

$X \subset (A \cup B)$

And now, how do we proceed proving that they are not equivalent?

Comment: to prove that they are not equal, find a set which is in $P(A\cup B)$, but not in $P(A)\cup P(B)$.

Comment: You are off to a good start.  So $X \subseteq A \cup B$.  Does this imply $\, X \subseteq A$? If so, then $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.  But we can't infer that $\, X \subseteq A$ necessarily.  Similarly, we can't infer $\, X \subseteq B$ necessarily.  Here is a specific example: Let $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$, and $B = \{2, 3 \}$.  Let $\, X = \{1, 3\}$.  $X$ is a subset of $A \cup B$, but it is neither a subset of $A$ nor a subset of $B$.

Comment: I assume we are talking power sets.  I misread the title as probability.

Comment: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345978/prove-that-if-mathcal-pa-cup-mathcal-pb-mathcal-pa-cup-b-then-eithe), and [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246491/stuck-with-proof-for-forall-a-forall-b-mathcalpa-cup-mathcalpb-mathc), and of course, [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003264/prove-there-exist-sets-a-b-with-mathcal-p-lefta-cup-b-right-not)...

Comment: Also [the comments here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/242137/622).

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $A\cup B$ is never in $P(A)\cup P(B)$ unless $A\cup B$ is a subset of $A$ or $B$ - which never happens unless $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4\}$. What are $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A\cup B)$?

Answer (score 2):

You can see it by the cardinality of the sets. Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2.\dotsc,b_m\}$ be disjoint sets.

We can see that $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$. This implies $|\mathcal P(A)|=2^n$ and $|\mathcal P(B)|=2^m$. Now $|\mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)|=2^n+2^m-1$ (because they both share $\emptyset$). However $|A\cup B|=m+n$ and $|\mathcal P(A\cup B)|=2^{m+n}$. Therefore $\mathcal P(A\cup B) \neq \mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)$.