# Is there an algebraic proof method for $\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

In our homework we are asked to prove $\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$. Both using the element argument proof method and algebraic proof method (using set identities). Is there a way to use set identities with power sets?

Comment: You won't be able to prove it, since it's not true.

Comment: Sorry it was the subset sign how can i indicate that

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  `$\subseteq$` produces $\subseteq$

Comment: Thx fixed it. Im new very sorry about that

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012538/why-pa-cup-pb-is-not-equivalent-to-pa-cup-b)

Comment: Are you allowed to use the identity $X\subseteq Y\ \Rightarrow\ \mathcal P(X)\subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$ in your proof using the "algebraic proof method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume the following identities for arbitrary sets $X,Y,Z$:

1. It holds that $X\subseteq X\cup Y$.
2. If $X\subseteq Z$ and $Y\subseteq Z$ then $X\cup Y\subseteq Z$.
3. If $X\subseteq Y$ then $\mathcal P(X)\subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$.

From this we can prove that for arbitrary sets $A,B$ we have $\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)\subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$ the following way:

By 1. we have both $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$. Hence, by 3. it follows that both $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$ and $\mathcal P(B)\subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B)$. By 2. this then implies that
$$
\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You just have to prove that $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ and similarly for $\mathcal P(B)$. Just observe that $A, B\subseteq A\cup B$ and remember inclusion is transitive.

Comment: Isn't that using the "element argument proof method", i.e. take an element of $\mathcal P(A)$ and show it is in $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$?

Comment: Not sure what the O.P. exactly meant  by ‘element argument proof’.  I'd think he meant considering the elements of a subset of $A$, not   subsets of $A$  as  elements of $\mathcal P(A)$.